# bash scripting , how to check if condition is true , it should check next 5 time or next 50 seconds same condition ,it true ,alert

Tags: bash

```
#! /bin/bash 
requestCount=( grep "stingTofind request in nginx total request in one minutes)

if [ $requestCount -gt 10 ]; then 

 ##here I am trying to check if conditation is true for next 2 minutes on every 30 second interval##

fi
```

Not sure how can i achieve this ..
Can anyone help me ?

Thanks,

Comment: You have to indent your code by four spaces or surround it with triple backtick lines so it shows up as code.

Comment: you can sleep different seconds up to the condition. if your script should always running, put it in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Write a function for your check. Then call the function in a loop. If the result is ok, exit the script. If the result is not ok, sleep for 30 seconds. After sleeping four times for 30 seconds, alert this.

```
#! /bin/bash

request_count() {
  echo $RANDOM
}

for n in {1..4}
do 
  if [ $(request_count) -gt 10 ]
  then
    echo "High load $n"
    sleep 30
  else
    echo "No panic"
    exit
  fi
done

echo "Panic now!"
exit 1
```